# Can the phrase, "bred as we" obey grammatical rule?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

> Exultation is the going
>
> Of an inland soul to sea,
>
> Past the houses—past the headlands—
>
> Into deep Eternity—

> **Bred as we**, among the mountains,
>
> Can the sailor understand
>
> The divine intoxication
>
> Of the first league out from land?

This is Emily Dickinson's poem. I somewhat understand the meaning of the bolded part but still don't know how come this phrase is possible grammatically? Can I see it as an adjective phrase?

Comment: Grammar shmammar. It is poetic license.

Comment: Emily Dickinson is renowned for her eccentric grammar, punctuation, and thought. Expecting her poems to match conventional standards of writing is like expecting a comedian to be 100% honest and factual.

Answer (score 2):

This is a subtle blending of two devices— one rhetorical and the other linguistic— to give a thorough poetic touch to the line.

The two devices being:

**Anastrophe**

> Inversion of the normal syntactic order of words; for example,

*“Matter too soft a lasting mark to bear” (Alexander Pope).*

[American Heritage Dictionary]

and

**Zero Copula**

> In grammar, zero copula refers to the absence of an explicit auxiliary verb (usually a form of the verb be) in certain constructions where it is customarily found in standard English. Also called copula deletion or understood copula.

[ThoughtCo.]